# WCF SOAP XML as Datasource for SSRS

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, reporting-services

I have a WCF service which returns the data for SSRS. As I am not able to call my Interface method in SSRS `rdl`.

`Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'CatReport'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'ParameterClass' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'CatReport' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' (mscorlib)`

**Interface code in WCF**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ResponseContr CatReport(ParameterClass bbb);
}
```

**ParameterClass**

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true)]
public class ParameterClass
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string InformationType { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string ItemLocation { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
}
```

**ResponseContr**

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true)]
public class ResponseContr
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

**Book Class**

```
[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int NoOfCopies { get; set; }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" contract="ReportingService.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding" />
</client>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                  logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
                  logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
                  logMalformedMessages="true"
                  maxMessagesToLog="5000"
                  maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000">
  </messageLogging>
</diagnostics>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ReportingService.LibraryServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ReportingService.LibraryServiceBehavior"
   name="ReportingService.Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
    binding="basicHttpBinding" name="BasicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding"
    contract="ReportingService.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex"
    binding="mexHttpBinding"
    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>




<!--<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      -->
<!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
<!--
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      -->
<!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
<!--
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>-->
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

**Implement Interface**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public ResponseContr CatReport(ParameterClass bbb)
    {
        return _clc.CatalogueList(bbb);
    }
}
```

**Rdl DataSet Query**

```
<Query>
<Method Namespace="http://tempuri.org/" Name="CatReport">
</Method>
<SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/IService1/CatReport</SoapAction>
</Query>
```

Any help to this problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the error message down into parts by sentence
A - Obviously an error with deserialization!
B - OK. The message body is invalid.
C - This tells us it's ParameterClass that isn't been added to the hierarchy.
D - CatReport is found, so it's below this.

Looking at the ParameterClass there appears to be a serialization directive but no element specified underneath. Suggested modification:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true)]
public class ParameterClass
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string InformationType { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string ItemLocation { get; set; }
}
```